# Fetching external mail through the internet via IMAP in linux

Tags: linux, port, imap, firewall, iptables

I am working on a project that requires me to enable fetching of external mail through the IMAP protocol.

I was wondering if there was any way to test this from for example imap.gmail.com without using telnet (as I have to enable the IMAP port and not telnet) ?

I do apologize if this is a trivial question, but I could not locate any way to do this, thanks!

Comment: you can try with command line tool like mutt,alpine etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can connect from the command line with this command:

```
gnutls-cli --crlf -p 993 imap.gmail.com
```

`gnutls-cli` establishes the TLS-encrypted connection, to port 993 (which is reserved for IMAP over TLS), and ends every line with `CR LF` as required by the IMAP protocol.  Then you can send commands, like `CAPABILITY`:

```
* OK Gimap ready for requests from 193.106.245.90 b136mb42616800wmb
x CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 XYZZY SASL-IR AUTH=XOAUTH AUTH=XOAUTH2 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN
x OK Thats all she wrote! b136mb42616800wmb
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems like what I am looking for!
A quick question though; How can I log in to my account and fetch a mail?

Comment: Use the `LOGIN`, `EXAMINE` and `FETCH` commands as described here: http://www.anta.net/misc/telnet-troubleshooting/imap.shtml